# How to Maintain a Minimum Number of Rows in a DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, datatable, datatables

I'm working on a project in chrome extension development where I have a DataTable that represents idle time data. I want to maintain a minimum of three rows in the DataTable at all times. When I add a new row by clicking the "Add" button, I want to ensure that there are always at least three rows visible, including the newly added row. Additionally, I want to remove empty rows whenever new row is added.

Currently, my code adds empty rows at the top of the table, which is not the behavior I want. I'm quite new to development, so I'm struggling with how to achieve this. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
(function () {
    console.log($('#lvIdleTime'));
    lvIdleTime = $('#lvIdleTime').DataTable({
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo": false,
        columns: [
            {
                "data": null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                    if (data.FromTime === null) {
                        return '';
                    }
                    return getHMSFromMili(data.FromTime);
                }
            },
            {
                "data": null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                    if (data.ToTime === null) {
                        return '';
                    }
                    return getHMSFromMili(data.ToTime);
                }
            },
            { data: 'Description' },
            { data: 'ActivityName' },
            { data: 'FromTime' },
            { data: 'ToTime' }
        ],
        setRowProps: () => ({
            onDoubleClick: (row, dataIndex) => {
                alert("double click!");
            }
        }),
        "columnDefs": [
            { "targets": [4, 5], "visible": false, "searchable": false }
        ],
    });
    //  // Remove any empty rows if necessary
    //  const dataRowCount = lvIdleTime.rows().data().length;
    //  const emptyRows = lvIdleTime.rows('.empty-row');
      
    //  if (dataRowCount >= 3 && emptyRows.length > 0) {
    //      emptyRows.every(function () {
    //          this.remove(); // Remove the empty row
    //      });
    //      lvIdleTime.draw(false); // Redraw without resetting the current paging position
    //  } 
    $("#BtnAdd").click(function () {
        if (SplitIdleTimeData()) {
            $('#divlvIdleTime').show();
            $('#resetDiv').show();
        }
    });

    // rest of the code
})();

function SplitIdleTimeData() {
    FromTimePicker = document.getElementById('txtFrom');
    ToTimePicker = document.getElementById('txtTo');
    // some more codes
    let data = {
        FromTime: GetDateTime(FromTimePicker.value, idledata.FromTime),
        ToTime: GetDateTime(ToTimePicker.value, idledata.ToTime),
        Description: $("#ActivityDescription").val(),
        ActivityName: $("#selActivity option:selected").text(),
        ActivityId: $("#selActivity option:selected").val()
    };
    $("#table tr td:nth-child(1)").each(function () {
        var texttocheck = this.innerText.trim();
        if (texttocheck == data.FromTime) {
            message = "Selected From Time and To Time is already exists in the list.";
            console.log("showing message: " + message);
            $("#alert-body").html('<p>' + message + '</p>');
            Modalalert.show();
            return false;
        }
    });
    console.log("the data is %o", data);
    console.log("the data is %s", JSON.stringify(data));
    lvIdleTime.row.add(data).draw(false);

    var rowCount = lvIdleTime.data().count();
    if (rowCount < 3) {
        addEmptyRows(2);
    }
function addEmptyRows(count) {
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        const data = {
            Description: '',
            ActivityName: '',
            FromTime: null,
            ToTime: null
        };
        const newRow = lvIdleTime.row.add(data).node();
        $(newRow).addClass('empty-row');
    }
    lvIdleTime.draw();
}
    SetNextTimeValueForDateControls();
    if (new Date(GetDateTimeWithoutSeconds(FromTimePicker.value)).getTime() >= new Date(GetDateTimeWithoutSeconds(ToTimePicker.value)).getTime()) {
        let compareDurationInSeconds = 59;
        if (lvIdleTime.rows().data().length > 0) {
            var dataFirst = lvIdleTime.rows(0).data()[0];
            FromTimePicker.value = new Date(idledata.FromTime).toTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit' }).substring(0, 8);
            ToTimePicker.value = new Date(dataFirst.ToTime).toTimeString([], { hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', second: '2-digit' }).substring(0, 8);
        }
    }
    $("#selActivity").prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    $("#ActivityDescription").val("");
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps re-read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask as suggested by others on your previously unanswered questions - making a reproducible example here as a snippet will go a long way towards allowing others to best help you. Create a working snippet IN your question including any HTML and CSS that might be of use.